# Jquery form validation prevent form submission

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

i'm using Jquery form validation, the validation works but my form still submits. I have tried adding "return false" but to no avail. The online documentation also seems to overlook valid form submission actions.

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){

     $("form#ticketSubmit").validate({

          rules:{

               name:{
                    required: true,
                    number: false
               }

          }

     });

     $('form#ticketSubmit').submit(function(){

          // DO SOME AJAX

     });

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is not showing any problem. Could you add more `submit` code?

Comment: are you trying to do ajax validation ? Else try `.on('submit',function(){...`

Comment: @Jeevan Jose if I put any other code in the first event binding it the code reports errors...

Answer (score 3):

```
 $(function(){

     $("form#ticketSubmit").validate({

          rules:{

               name:{
                    required: true,
                    number: false
               }

          }

     });


    $('form#ticketSubmit').submit(function(){
    var isvalidate=$("#form#ticketSubmit").valid();
            if(!isvalidate)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("invalid");
            }else{
     e.preventDefault();
    //Do AJAX
    }

         });
});
```

Comment: Should prevent default regardless of isvalidate.

Comment: use prevent default wen validate returns false
because we are using form.submit..

Comment: The ajax won't run as the form will submit and reload the page.

Comment: now in this code ur preventing the default right when the validation returns false so the form wont be submitted..
only if validation returns true ajax will fire since its in the else part...

Comment: You do realize you need to stop the form submission if you want to submit it by ajax ?

Comment: oh ya put event.preventDefault(); in the else part too

Comment: @patsy-issa Yes I have used return false and prevent default.. it foesn't work

Comment: @shashank I added the prevent default, the form styill submits

Comment: @AlanA then something else is submiting it for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
Working Example see whether this is use-full...


<html>
      <head>
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/site-demos.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/additional-methods.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">   



    jQuery.validator.addMethod("lettersonly", function(value, element) {
      return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z]+$/i.test(value);
    }, "Letters only please"); 

        jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
      debug: true,
      success: "valid"
    });
    $(function(){
    $('#myForm').validate({
    rules: {
             myPrice:{
                required: true,
                 lettersonly: true
                //number: false
                //denominationCheck:true
                }
            }

        });

        $('#submit').click(function(){


            if($('#myForm').valid())
            {
            //doAjax
            }else{
            alert("invalid credentials");
            }

        });

    });

    </script>
      </head>
      <body>    

                <form id="myForm">
                <input id="myPrice" type="text" name="myPrice" style="float: left;"/><br>
                <button id="submit">Validate!</button>
                </form>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you forgot to include [`jquery.validation.js.`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNjQueryValidate1111.ashx)

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
     $("form#ticketSubmit").validate({
          rules:{
               name:{
            required: true,
                    number: false
               }
          }          
     });    
     // if the "save to report" form is submitted 
     var isvalidate=$("#form#ticketSubmit").valid();    
     if(isvalidate){      
          $('form#ticketSubmit').submit(function(e){  
               e.preventDefault();
               var dataString=$(this).serialize();
               // Do some AJAX
          });
     }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rJ5pC/10/)**</kbd>

Comment: I still get the form submission

Comment: `preventDefault()` will stop submitting form. http://jsfiddle.net/5gLD8/. Share your code in fiddle it will be helpful to us.

Comment: Yes. can you setup your code with validation method in fiddle?

Comment: @unkown I created a jsfiddle here although it doesn't run 100% http://jsfiddle.net/rJ5pC/

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(function(){

         $("form#ticketSubmit").validate({

              rules:{

                   name:{
                        required: true,
                        number: false
                   }

              }

         });



        var isvalidate=$("#form#ticketSubmit").valid();
                if(!isvalidate)
                {

                    alert("invalid");
                }else{
    $('form#ticketSubmit').submit(function(){
event.preventDefault();
        //Do AJAX
    });
        }


    });

Use this
```

Comment: that doesn't work, now the form submits and doesn't do the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `submitHandler` option of jQuery Validate:

```
 $("form#ticketSubmit").validate({
      rules:{
           name:{
                required: true,
                number: false
           }
      },
      submitHandler: function(form){
          var data=$(form).serialize();
          //do your ajax with the data here
      }

 });
```